# Strong Goldbach Conjecture with set implementation

Tags: python, primes

I have devised my own version for a Goldbach verification project which uses sets to compare already sieved primes. My implementation also uses generators to "sieve a segment" since storing base 10 numbers in such an extensive list is memory intensive.
However, As in most cases, it is not as efficient as I would wish it to be. I hope to shorten the time complexity sufficiently by optimizing one of the implementations found in the program. In addition, to understand my program further, I used the difference in primes, which would be subtracted from the even number consecutively until the difference in the final set was zero.

## Set comprehension

```
 f_stack = {i for i in range(6, ((seg + 1)) * seg_size, 2)}
```

This piece is particularly slow in comparison to the rest of the program when n is sufficiently large. I garner that the loops themselves are also slow when n gets sufficiently large so I suppose some extreme loop unrolling in assembly would fix this, but there must be some more practical solution.

## General algorithm

The implementation I made I believe could have some improvements in the general algorithm that offers more performance, maybe some bitwise implementation, or another data structure that has the comparison functionalities of a set, yet maintains a more inordinate capacity for iterating . And maybe even an implementation that takes advantage of the clock speed on the cpu to maximize performance.  The most obvious performance increase would be to implement multiprocessing, but I wish to improve on the progression of the algorithm itself.

And yes I know that I do not have any if name main, and I also may have messed up on some of my type hints.

```
def primesieve (n:int) -> tuple:
    sieve = [True] * (n // 2)
    for i in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if sieve[i // 2]:
            sieve[i * i // 2::i] = [False] * ((n - i * i - 1) // (2 * i) + 1)
    return [2] + [2 * i + 1 for i in range(1, n// 2) if sieve[i]]


def split_list(a_list):
    half = len(a_list)//2

    return [0] + a_list[1:half]
def difference(primes: list):
    result = [b - a for a, b in zip(primes[:-1], primes[1:])]
    return result

def stack(seg: int, seg_size: int,pm: object, fuprime: set):
    if seg == 0:
        f_stack = {i for i in range(6, ((seg + 1)) * seg_size, 2)}
    else:
        f_stack = {i for i in range(seg * seg_size, ((seg + 1)) * seg_size, 2)}
    for j in pm:
        f_stack = {(i - j) for i in f_stack}
        f_stack = f_stack.difference(fuprime)
        yield f_stack
def prime_gen(prime:list):
    yield 0
    for i in prime:
        yield i

def main():
    limit = 10 ** 6
    fuprime = primesieve(limit)
    seg_size = 10 ** 6

    prime = split_list(fuprime)
    prime = difference(prime)
    for i in range(0, (limit // seg_size)):
        pm = prime_gen(prime)
        stacks = stack(i, seg_size, pm, fuprime)
        for sets in stacks:
            if sets.difference(fuprime) == set():
                break
            pass
main()
```

Comment: To use less memory you can optimize the sieve. You can take inspiration from [this](https://gist.github.com/user140242/712fd20e57287d47c8e51a03cb50842a).